# Is a sequence with this property convergent or at least bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(u_k)_{k=0}^\infty, (v_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ and $(w_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be nonnegative sequences that satisfy

1. $u_k^2-u_{k-1}^2\le v_k u_{k-1}+w_k$ for all $k \geq 1$
2. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty v_k < +\infty$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty w_k < +\infty$

I've come across this question while doing stuffs, and I suspect that the sequence $(u_k)$ is convergent. But I still haven't been able to either prove it or find a counter example. I don't know if there is any result regarding this available? Any idea/ answer would highly be appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to prove it for special cases (e.g., assuming monotonicity of $(v_k)_k$)?

Comment: @Clement C.   Well that's interesting but $(v_k)$ in my problem should not be monotone. That said, when assuming furthermore that $(v_k)$ is decreasing for instance, I didn't make any progress.

Comment: I see. I was asking since proofs for special cases sometimes give you an insight towards the general case, or a counterexample...

Comment: Yeah absolutely. Thank you for suggesting that anw. I just realized that for my problem it's necessary and sufficient to show only that $(u_k)$ is bounded. Wondering what trick to do here to bound $(u_k)$.

Comment: I think it can be shown that $u_n$ is bounded, but convergence seems to be more complicated.

Comment: I see it's no worries. If it's bounded, the convergence can be implied. Let me check your proof of boundedness. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle V=\sum^\infty_{k=1}v_k$, $\displaystyle W=\sum^\infty_{k=1}w_k$ and $\displaystyle m_n=\max_{1\le k\le n}u_k$. Then,
$$
u^2_k-u^2_0=\sum^k_{i=1}(u^2_i-u^2_{i-1})\le m_{k-1}\,\sum^k_{i=1}v_i+\sum^k_{i=1}w_i\le V\,m_{k-1}+W\le V\,m_n+W
$$
for $1\le k\le n$, so we must have
$$m^2_n\le V\,m_n+W+u^2_0,$$ and that means
$$u_n\le m_n\le V/2+\sqrt{V^2/4+W+u^2_0}.$$

Comment: That's right. I've come to the estimate using the max of $u_k$ but stop there and go for another direction since I think that's fruitless. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: With a similar argument, I think I can show convergence, too, but it doesn't get any prettier in the process. :-(

Comment: I agree. it's basically the same argument to show the convergence.

Comment: This is very neat! +1